# How to expand a table from a visualization in Looker?

Tags: looker-studio, looker

## How to expand a table from a visualization in Looker?

I understand that it is possible to expand a table from a visualization in Looker, having seen it in existing dashboards.

However, I have researched and have not been able to figure out how to do it myself.

[Single value visualization to expand a table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JT412.png)

**I hope to know how to expand its related table from a visualization.**

Answer (score 0):

You could use the option of drilled fields. In your look ML, Count measure provide the drill fields to show once user clicks on the tile.

```
measure: count {
  type: count
  drill_fields: [field_1, field_2,...]
}
```